# Convert earth engine feature collection to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, java, collections, google-earth-engine

I uploaded a shapefile in my earth engine account as a feature collection and I now I need to use it in a jupyter lab notebook.

I use the following code to import the collection:

```
df = ee.FeatureCollection('users/my_user/my_shape')
```

But now I don't know how to convert to into a dataframe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this using [geemap](https://geemap.org/notebooks/geopandas/).

`gdf = geemap.ee_to_pandas(df)`

Answer (score 1):

Feature collection to pandas dataframe:

```
nested_list = results.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(len(column_df)), column_df).values().get(0)
data = nested_list.getInfo()
data

# dont forget we need to call the callback method "getInfo" to retrieve the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_df)
# we obtain the data frame as per our demand
df
```

You can visit the blog post:
https://kaflekrishna.com.np/blog-detail/extraction-raster-values-point-samples-google-earth-engine-gee/

Find: "Method 1: Feature collection to pandas dataframe" on step 11, then you can convert feature collection to pandas dataframe, you will find the whole case scenario in which I faced & used this example as well.

Comment: Hi Krishna. how can I make this conversion with a feature collection with many elements (the max=5000)? I realized this conversion using getInfo() breaks when I try to do this.  Is there any way to workaround this?